# Comparing the row with other row within same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about the SQL Query.

[image]

Basically, I would like to get a sample value from the testCategory = compareTestCat and testType = compTestType.

I am not really sure if we can compare the first row with the fourth row within the same query.
Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Look up self join (details will depend on the rest of the query which we don't know).

Answer (score 2):

Try `SELF JOIN` to compare values within the same table.

Try the Following:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM YourTable A
JOIN YourTable B ON A.testCategory = B.compareTestCat and A.testType = B.compTestType
```

A and B are the different alias names for the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very sparse information you provided, this looks like what you need:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        TestTable 
    WHERE 
            testCategory = compareTestCat 
        AND testType = compTestType;
```

**UPDATE**

If you are interested in comparing different rows in the same table with each other, then you will need to go with a `self join` on the table. Examples of solutions for this have already been provided by others.

Comment: Can you give some SQL fiddle example for your query. It returns null. Because he wants to compare first row with 4th row. Not the same rows.

Comment: @DineshDB I guess this is what happens when the interpretation of the question is left up to those of us who are answering it.